# How to get occurrence of data and insert it to list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table warehouse that has two rows (ProductId and Quantity).

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ProductId ! Quantity +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1003     !    2     +
+  1151     !    1     +
+  2546     !    4     +
+  2659     !    3     +
+  3005     !    6     +
```

I'm working on Linq, what I need to achieve is to generate a single list of data (productId) for all,
according to the number of occurrences found in quantity row.

**For instance :**

*productId 1003 has quantity 2, so in the created list, generate 2 items 1003; as there's already one, generate 2 - 1 which is 1 more.*

*productId 2659 has quantity 3, so in the created list, generate 3 items 2659, as there's already one, generate 3 - 1 which is 2 more*

Simply put, the number of count in quantity field, must be the number of productId for each line.

All the productId should be in one single list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a dictionary of `<int, int>`:

```cs
dictionary.SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i.Key, i.Value)).ToList();
```